# Persistent disk problem on Kubernetes GCP

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, persistent-storage, directus

I'm working in Kubernetes in GCP and I'm having problems with volumes and persistent disks.

I'm using Directus 7 (CMS Headless), which saves most of its information in the database except the files that are uploaded, these files are in the **/var/www/html/public/uploads** folder (tested locally with docker-compose and works fine), and that folder is the one I'm trying to save on the persistent disk.

No error occurs but when restart the Kubernetes Pod i lose the uploaded images (they are not being saved on the disk).

This is my configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: directus-pv
  namespace: default
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  capacity:
    storage: 100G
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: directus-disk
    fsType: ext4

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: directus-pvc
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: .....
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  volumeName: directus-pv
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100G
```

And in the deploy.yaml:

```
    volumeMounts:
      - name: api-disk
        mountPath: /var/www/html/public/uploads
        readOnly: false

  volumes:
  - name: api-disk
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: directus-pvc
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried using the PVC to automatically create the PV?

Comment: Yes but the same result

Comment: not so sure if this is going to help, but I tried something similar and it worked, the difference was that I removed the `readOnly: false` statement and set `mountPath` to `/var/www/html`, using PVC to create the PV on its own. It would not make sense for this to be a fix, but try it. If that doesn't work (which is likely) there is probably something you are missing on the cluster, maybe then go ahead and try it on a new cluster.

Comment: Do you use GKE or custom solution on GCP ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove namespace property from pv and pvc manifest. They are shared resources in the cluster.
Remove storage class property as well.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that your manually provisioned persistence volume **directus-pv**, is being created somehow with PersistentVolumeReclaimPolicy=*[Recycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#recycle). That's the only possible reason that could cause data erase on each POD restart.

I'm not able to reproduce your case with the provided manifest files, 
but I tried the following test:

1. Create gcePersistentDisk
2. Create PersistentVolume
3. Create PersistentVolumeClaim
4. Create ReplicaSet (replicas=1) like this one

```html
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: busybox-list-uploads
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: busybox-list-uploads
        version: "2"
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: busybox
          args: [/bin/sh, -c, 'sleep 9999' ]
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/www/html/public/uploads
              name: api-disk
          name: busybox
      volumes:
      - name: api-disk
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: directus-pvc
```

5. Write some file into mounted folder /var/www/html/public/uploads
6. Restart POD (=kill the POD) by resizing replica to 0 then to 1
7. List content of /var/www/html/public/uploads on newly created POD

> for i in busybox-list-uploads-dgfbc; do kubectl exec -it $i -- ls /var/www/html/public/uploads; done;
>   lost+found                          picture_from_busybox-list-uploads-ng4t6.png

As you can see output shows clearly, that data survives POD restart

* you can verify it with cmd: `kubectl get pv/directus-pv -o yaml`